# Uploading many images to Facebook

Tags: facebook

Facebook has a limit of about <s>60</s> 200 pictures per album. Is there a way to take a few hundred pictures, and upload them to a series of albums (e.g. "Foo part 1/5", "Foo part 2/5", ...) ?

Comment: Maybe I am looking at something else but is it not 200/album?

Comment: Hmm, I remembered a lower limit, haven't tried it recently though. The question is still valid though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your OS, there's iPhoto, Picasa, and Windows Live Photo Gallery.

The preferred method (which I like a lot) is to use Picasa ([download link](http://picasa.google.com/)) and upload them.

If you're going to use iPhoto, you'll need to select all the photos you want to upload, goto Share and then Facebook.

For Windows Live Photo Gallery ([download link](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-photo-gallery)), get this addon for facebook ([download link](http://liveuploadfacebook.codeplex.com/)) and look at their screenshots for specific instructions.

This is the quickest way I've been able to upload more than a few photos at a time.